# How can I create an animation of many ants spawning from a central point and fanning outward?

Tags: animation, particles, physics, geometry-nodes, instances

I have a single animation of an ant walking across a plane and I'd like to use that as the base for a larger animation with hundreds of them spawning from a central point and walking outward in various directions away from that point. Think about ants emerging from a small ant hill and spreading out from that point.

I'm relatively new at this so I'm looking for the optimal way to do something like this without having to individually animate every single ant to move in a random vector away from the spawn point. I have spent a few hours fiddling with particle systems to see if that might suit my purpose. I managed to spawn particles that are instances of my ant collection, but I have been unable to figure out how to control the path of the particles to the degree that I'd need for such an animation.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Search for "blender birds" on the internet.  There is such a thing in other 3D software that I can't mention that allows you to create such behavioral simulations.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely search for that. Much appreciated.

Comment: You could also search for "blender boids", this way you avoid most of the bird modelling tutorials ;)

Comment: I found a flock of birds tutorial and it was perfect. Thanks so much! Also I feel dumb for going over almost every inch of the particle system, seeing "boids" and going "huh, weird" and then going right on past it. smh lol

Comment: @Chev It would be great to know how you did it because your particles seem to have several goals, maybe write an answer?

Comment: @moonboots sure! I’m busy this morning but I’ll throw an answer together later today and include a link to my particle test blend file.

Comment: @moonboots I do have this TikTok sized render on my phone in case you want to see the result. Each particle is an instance of a collection that contains a complex object with the cone “hat” being animated separately just to show that particles can be objects that are animated. I’ll be applying it to my actual scene soon but for now this proof of concept is all I have :) https://imgur.com/a/3QSKfDY

Comment: thanks but how did you set the boids so that they go in different directions?

Comment: It’ll all be in the answer when I’m at the computer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks a bit toxic, but this might be of interest to you....

[image]
[Here you can see the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TUt1W19YS4)

And of course, you can push it to the limits and make your GPU glow if you want:

[image]

With this setup you can actually use any shape for an ant hill.

For the sake of simplicity, I used the same shape in this example with which I implemented the individual ant trails.

At the beginning I use the top surface of a cylinder (with sufficient subdivision):

[image]

Then move the points with a *Noise Texture*:

[image]

Using the nodes `Shortest Edge Paths` and `Edge Paths to Curves` (available since Blender 3.3!) I convert the mesh into individual curves and trim them:

[image]

I can then conveniently time the trim of the curves:

[image]

Not only from one point, but also from another point:

[image]

This way I get the necessary lines, which I then only have to divide into points:

[image]

Ants can then be instantiated at these points or whatever.

You can control the distances between the points, the start point and end point of the curve, as well as the speed and many other things...

Of course this is only an example and you would have to adjust some things here, but it could be a good starting help for you.

The nodes are a bit more extensive than usual, but it's not exactly an easy task:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.3+)*</sub>